# Select only one table row and Deselect others

Tags: android, listview, android-tablelayout

I have a table layout with table rows being added dynamically from the database. I need to programmatically choose only one table row and deselect the previous choosen. Similar to a listview onItemClick. For some reasons I can't use a ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add click listener on table rows. See the code below:

```
private int selectedIndex = -1;

private TableLayout tableLayout;

private void initTableLayout() {
    View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
            if (index != null) {
                selectRow(index);
            }
        }
    };

    tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table_layout);
    final TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setTag(0);
    tr.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    // Add views on tr

    tableLayout.addView(tr, 0, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    final TableRow tr2 = new TableRow(this);
    tr2.setTag(1);
    tr2.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    // Add views on tr2

    tableLayout.addView(tr2, 1, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ....

}

private void selectRow(int index) {
    if (index != selectedIndex) {
        if (selectedIndex >= 0) {
            deselectRow(selectedIndex);
        }
        TableRow tr = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(index);
        tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);  // selected item bg color
        selectedIndex = index;
    }
}

private void deselectRow(int index) {
    if (index >= 0) {
        TableRow tr = (TableRow) tableLayout.getChildAt(index);
        tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    }
}
```